# Regarding doubt in proof of estimating coefficients of cusp forms

Tags: analytic-number-theory, modular-forms

I am self studying analytic number theory from Tom M Apostol  Modular functions and Dirichlet series in number theory and I couldn't think about this deduction in theorem 6.17 .

> My doubt is in 3rd line of image 2 which I am adding that how product $\phi$ ($\tau $ ) = |f($\tau$) | $g^k $ ($\tau$) is invariant under transformation of $\Gamma $.
>
> I am not able to think how function $\phi $ becomes invariant under $\Gamma$ .
>
> See bottom for images.

Can somebody please give a hint.
[image]

[image]

Comment: Did you try to calculate $\varphi(A \tau)$? You know how $f$ transforms, you know how $g$ transforms. There's almost nothing to do.

Comment: @Paul K yes you are right  .